# А возможно ли создавать файлы с помощью JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Мне бы хотелось бы узнать, а возможно ли создавать файлы с помощью JavaScript? Если да, пожалуйста, приведите примеры. Буду очень рад вашему ответу.
 Спасибо заранее!

Comment: [Можно](http://jsfiddle.net/uselesscode/qm5ag/)

Comment: @Venta, приведите примеры.

Comment: Нажмите на слово `Можно`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать [FileSystem API](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112286/) (файлы окажутся в песочнице), можно заворачивать текст/изображение в Blob и загружать с помощью ссылки (вот [отличная небольшая библиотека](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/), рекомендую).

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: А можно сохранить не скачивая, а к примеру корневой папки сайта?

Comment: @Wicopee, да, только это вообще в другую сторону. Нужно определиться с тем, в каком формате передавать данные (можно прямо в теле запроса, а параметры в GET или заголовках, можно использовать [multipart/form-data](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt)) сформировать запрос и отправить с [XMLHttpRequest](https://habrahabr.ru/post/120917/).